# Mouse Colony Software

Tags: software, mouse, mice

I am looking for a good mouse colony census program that tracks the mice we have in the lab, breeding success of breeders, lineages, multiple user access, etc. Jackson labs has a program that does this but is is cumbersome and a bit pricey (softmouse is also an option, though a pricey one). I figured that since colony management is so pervasive there must be a good piece of software to deal with this, but have mostly been out of luck. It would also be great if it is currently supported software that isn't outdated and free or sold at a relatively cheap price. Thanks.

Comment: check this out: http://e-mouselab.com

Comment: When you mean track the mice, you mean like mice movement?

Comment: And what counts as cheap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of programs that could work:

- E-mouse Lab: http://e-mouselab.com, seems like the best fit for your requirements.
- ZooEasy: http://standalone.zooeasy.com/en/pedigree-software/breeding-mice/breeders/index.html, Cheaper, good for breeding and pedigrees.
- LabGuru: http://www.labguru.com, seems very professional and great for mice specimens as well.
- MouseHouseApp: http://www.mousehouseapp.com, This is an iPhone and iPad app, so this would be good in the lab, but it depends on whether or not you have an iOS device.

Also, from what I found, Jackson Labs actually offers free mouse colony management programs. It does seem like it is cumbersome, but also a great program.

I will add more when I get time.